# How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, printing

I have a very long-running stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 that I'm trying to debug, and I'm using the 'print' command to do it. The problem is, I'm only getting the messages back from SQL Server at the very end of my sproc - I'd like to be able to flush the message buffer and see these messages immediately during the sproc's runtime, rather than at the very end.

Comment: Just a short notice for people who'll (like me) think the answers don't work for them: be sure to switch to "Messages" tab when the query is running. By default you'll see the "Results" tab.

Comment: I'm on Messages and still get nothing.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Use the [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) function:

```
RAISERROR( 'This message will show up right away...',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

You shouldn't completely replace all your prints with raiserror.  If you have a loop or large cursor somewhere just do it once or twice per iteration or even just every several iterations.

Also: I first learned about RAISERROR at this link, which I now consider the definitive source on SQL Server Error handling and definitely worth a read:
http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

Comment: Note that TRY/CATCH in SQL will only catch errors with severity > 10, so using RAISERROR in this way won't jump into your CATCH statement. Which is great, as it means you can still use RAISERROR like this with TRY/CATCH. ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: Note that this doesn't work after the first 500 messages; once you print more than that it suddenly starts buffering!

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej No, I'm still running long-running processes using RAISEERROR, and just dealing with the fact that after a while, messages start getting buffered. It appears the only solution would be to use a different tool other than SSMS.

Comment: I think this is something that changed in a recent version of SS. Way back when I first wrote this we used RAISERROR for extensive logging of overnight batch processes with many more than 500 messages, and it wasn't a problem. But a lot can change in 7 years.

Comment: Some more details in this q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608989/can-i-print-immediately-for-each-iteration-in-a-loop why this won't work in sqlcmd in recent versions

Comment: At @GendoIkari's notice. I've tried it with ssms from 2016SP1 with this script. At 500 it switches to buffering 50 lines and at 1k it switches to 100 lines each. This continued at least until 2k, but then I stopped the script.
    declare @i int set @i = 0
    declare @t varchar(100)
    while 1=1 begin
        set @i = @i + 1
        set @t = 'print ' + convert(varchar, @i)
        RAISERROR (@t, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        waitfor delay '00:00:00.010'
    end

Answer (score 61):

Building on the answer by @JoelCoehoorn, my approach is to leave all my PRINT statements in place, and simply follow them with the RAISERROR statement to cause the flush.

For example:

```
PRINT 'MyVariableName: ' + @MyVariableName
RAISERROR(N'', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

The advantage of this approach is that the PRINT statements can concatenate strings, whereas the RAISERROR cannot. (So either way you have the same number of lines of code, as you'd have to declare and set a variable to use in RAISERROR).

If, like me, you use AutoHotKey or SSMSBoost or an equivalent tool, you can easily set up a shortcut such as "]flush" to enter the RAISERROR line for you. This saves you time if it is the same line of code every time, i.e. does not need to be customised to hold specific text or a variable.

Comment: Note that `RAISERROR()` does support `printf()`-style string interpolation. For example, if `@MyVariableName` is a stringish type (e.g., `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, etc.), you can use `RAISERROR()` with one line: `RAISERROR(N'MyVariableName: %s', 0, 1, @MyVariableName)`.

Comment: This is so convenient! I know that RAISERROR can do some simple substitution, but try substituting a [date]time, or calling a function from inside the RAISERROR statement! This answer gives you a simple FLUSH in the form of raising empty error (at the cost of a newline).

Answer (score 21):

Yes... The first parameter of the RAISERROR function needs an NVARCHAR variable.  So try the following;

```
-- Replace PRINT function
DECLARE @strMsg NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT @strMsg = 'Here''s your message...'
RAISERROR (@strMsg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

OR

```
RAISERROR (n'Here''s your message...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Comment: Look at the Messages tab on the bottom, next to Results tab or switch to Results To Text mode.

Comment: To switch to Results to Text mode, in SSMS, menu Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> General -> Default Destination for Results, and choose "Results to Text" instead of "Results to Grids", re-open the query window and then you won't sit there looking at a blank Results tab like a dummy while the RAISERROR output goes to the Messages tab.

Answer (score 14):

Another better option is to not depend on PRINT or RAISERROR and just load your "print" statements into a ##Temp table in TempDB or a permanent table in your database which will give you visibility to the data immediately via a SELECT statement from another window.  This works the best for me.  Using a permanent table then also serves as a log to what happened in the past.  The print statements are handy for errors, but using the log table you can also determine the exact point of failure based on the last logged value for that particular execution (assuming you track the overall execution start time in your log table.)

Comment: This might be an issue if you are writing a truly transactional script with commit and rollback. I don't believe you will be able to query your temp table live - and it will go away if your transaction fails.

Comment: @SteveJ you can query it live by using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` in your monitoring session

Comment: @TheConstructor ; That is a helpful tip - I'll make use of that, thanks. However, aren't we still left with the temp table going away on rollback? If doing failure analysis, it seems like that would be a big shortcoming.

Comment: @SteveJ yes, there is certainly this. You can of course copy the data in a `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction to another table, but you probably miss the moment just before `ROLLBACK`. So it probably solves the 'how far?' not the 'why rollback?'

Comment: With most errors, if you `SET XACT_ABORT OFF;` and rollback manually in a catch block or by other error detection means, you can save your logs from rollback via a table variable (be sure to use a table var as they are not affected by transaction rollbacks, but temp tables are):

`
-- at beginning
DECLARE @maxLogId INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM LogTable);

-- do stuff

-- error handling
DECLARE @tmpLog TABLE (/* log table cols */);
INSERT INTO @tmpLog
SELECT * FROM LogTable
WHERE ID > @maxLogId;

ROLLBACK TRAN;

-- set identity insert on and reinsert contents of tmpLog
`

Answer (score 5):

Just for the reference, **if you work in scripts (batch processing), not in stored procedure**, flushing output is triggered by the GO command, e.g.

```
print 'test'
print 'test'
go
```

In general, my conclusion is following: output of mssql script execution, executing in SMS GUI or with sqlcmd.exe, is flushed to file, stdoutput, gui window on first GO statement or until the end of the script.

Flushing inside of stored procedure functions differently, since you can not place GO inside.

Reference: [tsql Go statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

Comment: `go` doesn't just flush output, it ends the batch as per the link you provided. Anything you `declare`d is discarded, so not very usable for debugging. `declare @test int print "I want to read this!" go set @test=5` will though you an error claiming `@test` is undefined because it is in a new batch.

Comment: I agree, this is not proper answer to this question, but I put the answer (see disclaimer on the start) since it could be useful for someone else - e.g. someone who runs batch sql.

Answer (score 2):

To extend [Eric Isaac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36703942/4255824), here is how to use the table approach correctly:

Firstly, if your sp uses a transaction, you won't be able monitor the contents of the table live, unless you use the `READ UNCOMMITTED` option:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_log WITH (READUNCOMMITTED);
```

or

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT *
FROM table_log;
```

To solve rollback issues, put an increasing ID on the log table, and use this code:

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION mytran;
  -- already committed logs are not affected by a potential rollback
  -- so only save logs created in this transaction
  DECLARE @max_log_id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table_log);
  /*
   * do stuff, log the stuff
   */

  COMMIT TRANSACTION mytran;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @log_table_saverollback TABLE
  (
    ID INT,
    Msg NVARCHAR(1024),
    LogTime DATETIME
  );
  
  INSERT INTO @log_table_saverollback(ID, Msg, LogTime)
  SELECT ID, Msg, LogTime
  FROM table_log
  WHERE ID > @max_log_id;

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION mytran; -- this deletes new log entries from the log table

  SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_log ON;

  INSERT INTO table_log(ID, Msg, LogTime)
  SELECT ID, Msg, LogTime
  FROM @log_table_saverollback;

  SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_log OFF;
END CATCH
```

Notice these important details:

1. `SET XACT_ABORT OFF;` prevents SQL Server from just shutting down the entire transaction instead of running your catch block, always include it if you use this technique.
2. Use a `@table_variable`, not a `#temp_table`. Temp tables are also affected by rollbacks.