# SQL Server: PRINT output doesn't appear immediately

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2005 Management Studio, it appears that the output of PRINT statements doesn't appear immediately: If I have a PRINT statement followed by a long-running statement, the PRINT output doesn't appear until after the following statement.

Is there any way to flush the output earlier? I'm running some upgrade scripts that take an age to complete, and I'd like to know how far along the script is (so I know whether to wait a few minutes and then start the next one, or whether to go to lunch).

Comment: Do you have a "GO" between the PRINT and long running statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql)

Comment: Roger: I saw your ranting at http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2006/10/19/bad-ui-why-sql-query-analyzer-sucks.  I have the same complaint.  Why do I need to see my login info and the words "SQLQuery999.sql " on that short space which crowds out all the other important info, right?!  Glad to see you speak up although it won't change a thing. I have to resort to use the interface provided by the Visual Studio using the Server explorer so less deadly accident can happen.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

No. Output of PRINT statements will only be returned when a transaction is committed, when other record sets are returned or a statement is completed (`go` statement terminator in a SQL batch).  You can use [raiserror](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) at non-fatal error levels (0-18) to get immediate feedback of this sort.  For example:

```
RAISERROR ('Foo', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Comment: In my tests, PRINTs before RAISERROR will print out

Comment: The prints will appear before the output from the RAISERROR but they won't be returned to the client until the exception is raised.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the below line immediately after PRINT statement:

```
RAISERROR(N'', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

This will print the message immediately in the Messages tab during execution.