# T-SQL Output Message During execution in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query which loops and I want to see the PRINT messages during the execution. The query is something like this:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'
    PRINT 'here'
END
```

The `PRINT 'here'` does not output until I stop the process. However, I want to see it while it's running. Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that the prints get buffered, releasing "chunks" as the buffer fills up.

try using raiserror:

[How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql)

Answer (score 34):

You can use RAISERROR with serverity 0 and the NOWAIT option

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'
    RAISERROR ('here', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work after the first 500 messages; once you print more than that it suddenly starts buffering!

Comment: Doesn't work for me in SSMSv 18.1. Maybe things have changed sinze 2015...

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```sql
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE ( @i <= 10)
BEGIN
    --- do something
    SELECT 'Completed  ' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(50)) + '  :  ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(50));
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: Could you format your code according to the markdown rules please?

Answer (score 0):

current suggestions don't work for SSMS 18 and above.
Print then raiserror(N'', 0, 1) seems to get around this.