# Why Is My Azure SQL Database Table Permanently Locked?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an isolated Azure SQL test database that has no active connections except my development machine through SSMS and a development web application instance. I am the only one using this database.

I am running some tests on a table of ~1M records where we need to do a large `UPDATE` to data in nearly all of the ~1M records.

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000

WHILE @BatchSize > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize)
        [MyTable]
    SET
        [Data] = [Data] + ' a change'
    WHERE
        [Data] IS NOT NULL

    SET @BatchSize = @@ROWCOUNT
    RAISERROR('Updated %d records', 0, 1, @BatchSize) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

This query works fine, and I can see my data being updated 1000 records at a time every few seconds.

Performing additional `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` commands on `MyTable` seem to be somewhat affected by this batch query running, but these operations do execute within a few seconds when ran. I assume this is because locks are being taken on `MyTable` and my other commands will execute in between the batch query's locks/looping iterations.

This behavior is all expected.

However, every so often while the batch query is running I notice that additional `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` commands on `MyTable` will no longer execute. They always time out/never finish. I assume some type of lock has occurred on `MyTable`, but it seems that the lock is never being released. Further, even if I cancel the long-running update batch query I can still no longer run any `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` commands on `MyTable`. Even after 10-15 minutes of the database sitting stale with nothing happening on it anymore I cannot execute write commands on `MyTable`. The only way I have found to "free up" the database from whatever is occurring is to scale it up and down to a new pricing tier. I assume that this pricing tier change is recycling/rebooting the instance or something.

I have reproduced this behavior multiple times during my testing today.

What is going on here?

Comment: Why are you raising an error inside your loop? Wouldn't a print statement be a bit simpler?

Comment: @SeanLange `RAISERROR` prints messages as they happen, vs `PRINT` buffering the messages. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287878/t-sql-output-message-during-execution-in-ssms

Comment: Interesting. I have never needed to view messages as they happen like this. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling up/down the tier rollback all open transactions and disconnect server logins.

About what you are seeing it seems is lock escalation. Try to serialize access to the database using [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql). You can also try [lock hints](http://www.sqlnotes.info/tag/lock-hints/).

Comment: So I lied. There was a previous iteration of my batch update script that had a transaction involved with it. I think what's been happening here is that when I cancel the query in SSMS during my testing I am leaving open transactions which eventually lock the table. I will do more testing to confirm. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I just finished testing the scenario again and that was it. I committed all the open transactions and the table is unlocked.

Comment: Wonderful! Nice job.