# SQL Server : delay before output (a print statement) is produced

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I may have a slight feeling as to what is going on, but I thought I'd ask to get confirmation, and potentially look at an alternative.

As a slight background, I've written a C# application that is providing a small front end to a stored procedure. The procedure contains a number of temporary table inserts from other stored procedures (and one table valued udf), and some xml processing.

In order to get a sense of how far along I am in the stored procedure, I'm subscribing to the `InfoMessage` (using an `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler`) from an `SqlConnection`. I've put some informative print statements in various places throughout the SP, so I can get a sense of the processing which has completed and update a status bar accordingly).

The rough structure of the SP is along these lines:

```
Print 'Beginning processing'

Create Temp Table
Insert into Temp Table from Table Valued UDF

Print 'Creating working Tables'
Create more Temp Tables
Insert into Temp Tables from SPs (each SP contains a print statement e.g 'Starting SP1').
```

All the messages are received and processed successfully, but there is a delay of a few seconds before any messages are returned from the server, then the first few arrive all at once (as though they were all processed but the output was held back for a while).

I had naively assumed (I still have a lot to learn about DB mechanics) that my initial print statement would be returned before any of the other processing instructions within the SP took place.

I assume that the server is doing something regarding fetching execution plans an/or potentially recalculating plans, or is it the case that query optimiser is doing some preprocessing before any results at all are returned?

Hopefully my question is reasonably understandable from that mess of text. Essentially, would the query optimiser make the server perform some of the selects/inserts before the procedure actually begins sequentially encountering my print statements?

I also tried doing some small temp table manipulation before my initial print statement, so some rows would be returned before the slow operations began but the result was much the same.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql)

Comment: I think you're probably right, I didn't quite know the best way to explain what was happening so I didn't manage to find that when searching, Thanks!

I had assumed there was something actually messing around with the execution order, rather than it being a buffering issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can judge by MSSM, when you use PRINT statements they are late because of output happens once buffer is full. If you would like to output message straight away use:

RAISERROR('Message',0,0) WITH NOWAIT

It will work as Print but will be outputted straight away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea why it didn't occur to me to look at RAISEERROR, I think because print was working it had just passed me by.
What you posted doesn't actually change my behaviour, but with some googling I discovered the "WITH NOWAIT" clause, which is just what I'm after:
RAISERROR('Message',0,0) WITH NOWAIT

Allows me to get the message before anything else happens. I'm not sure if there's any associated performance worries. I read:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/

Thanks for the tip =D

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use SELECT statement instead of PRINT -

```
SELECT 'Beginning processing'

Create Temp Table
Insert into Temp Table from Table Valued UDF

SELECT 'Creating working Tables'

Create more Temp Tables
Insert into Temp Tables from SPs (each SP contains a print statement e.g 'Starting SP1').
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In this case 'select' will send the output to the results window, which could certainly be used, but I don't believe it will trigger the InfoMessage which I'm using to detect messages in my application. Thanks for the suggestion.