# WAITFOR RECEIVE results offset/delayed by 1 result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, service-broker

I'm using SQL Service Broker.  One connection SENDS a message on a queue with an XML message.  I have an independent connection that is `WAITFOR (RECEIVE TOP (1) ...), TIMEOUT 5000`.  This goes in a `WHILE (1=1)` loop in a single Management Studio query or a single ADO.NET SQL command execution with looped reader.NextResult().

All that seems to be correctly configured as I eventually get every result I expect.

But the problem is that the most recent result is always held back!

Let's say it's been running and there have been no `SEND`s, so it just keeps timing out with "None" printed to the console every 5 seconds.

Well now I `SEND` from SQL Management Studio query.  The `SEND` command completes successfully and immediately.  I immediately get a "None" in the console *before* the normal timeout interval.  Then at the *next* timeout interval, my "Update" event appears!

And if I `SEND` two messages after a run of "None"s, then I'll immediately get "None" and then one "Update".  Again, at the *next* timeout interval, the second "Update" will appear.

I can `SEND` ten messages and immediately get a "None" and nine "Update"s.  Then I wait the five seconds timeout and get the final "Update".

All `SEND`s are on the same conversation and I never end the conversation.  I do not RETAIN.

If I do a dirty read of the queue while the RECEIVE loop is running, the queue is always empty.  If I stop the RECEIVE loop, it fills up.  If I RECEIVE from another Management Studio query window, an additional clue is that when I stop the query, the final output always appears.  These two facts make me think that the queue is being dequeued right away, but that something is latching on the reader side (but what??).

At first I figured it was just a weird behavior of Management Studio that I've seen before where `PRINT`(?) is sometimes delayed.  But I would not expect that same behavior to show up in ADO.NET

Perhaps it has nothing to do with SSB, just the WAITFOR or just the streaming of multiple ResultSets.  I will investigate those options, but I'm hoping someone might recognize this in the meantime.

Are these symptoms familiar to you?

Thanks!

- Is there some way to allow results to be flushed to the connection before the next blocking action?  Is result/resultset delivery deferred?
- I don't see any extra locking in sp_lock results immediately following the `SEND` (nor otherwise)

---

For @Rikalous, here is the ADO.NET

```
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "upWaitForReceive";

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read()) // Individual messages received
            {
                string eventType = reader["EventType"] as string;

                // do something with the message
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult()); // next batch
    }
}
```

The sql loop is:

```
SELECT 'Initialized' AS EventType

WHILE (1=1) BEGIN
    ;DECLARE 
        @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        @MessageTypeName SYSNAME, 
        @MessageBody XML

    ;WAITFOR(
        RECEIVE TOP (1) @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle, @MessageTypeName = message_type_name, @MessageBody = message_body
        FROM [dbo].[{0}_EventsQueue]
    ), TIMEOUT 5000

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) BEGIN
        SELECT 'None' AS EventType; -- Allow the blocking call to spin anyway
        CONTINUE;
    END

    IF (@MessageTypeName = ...) BEGIN
        SELECT ...
    END ELSE IF (@MessageTypeName = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog') BEGIN
        END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
        SELECT @Message = 'Conversation Terminated' -- Not Expected
        RAISERROR (@Message, 11, 1)
        RETURN
    END
END

;END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle -- This will never be reached.  But if it were, this is what should be done
```

Comment: Can you post the full T-SQL please?

Comment: @Rikalous - the nature of SSB is so long-winded - do you have a specific hunch or a particular part that you would need to see?  I'm hoping someone just recognizes the issue.  I haven't distilled it into a simpler test case yet.

Comment: My first hunch is that SSMS may be part of the problem, have you tested this without having SSMS involved?

Comment: Yes.  I tested first with SSMS and then with an ADO.NET client connection (C#)

Comment: So how are you using the ADO.Net connection, running an ExecuteReader? Can you show us that code?

Comment: Added some code.  You may notice that I handle multiple results in C# where I only `RECEIVE TOP (1)` in SQL, but the message includes perhaps multiple items encoded in the message which get split into multiple results.

Comment: why are you using a SP and not doing the RECEIVE directly from ado.net?

Comment: @jgauffin - I think fundamentally you're suggesting that the loop be performed in C# rather than on SQL.  One reason is the parsing of the XML message which I wish to do in SQL.  There are other reasons.  But otherwise, I am really using a text command and I just fudged it for this code listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe RAISERROR (...) WITH NOWAIT should flush the buffer but I didn't play with it for quite some time.

Comment: Yes, `RAISERROR ('FLUSH', 1, 1) WITH NOWAIT` at the beginning of the loop does seem to fix the problem.

Comment: This probably wins.  Is there anything bad about using raiserror?  Now that I know this works, is there an even better way to correct for the buffering without raiserror?  Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's bad from performance point of view but I don't think you will run into troubles with your DBA.

Comment: Will I get bounty? :)

Answer (score 1):

Print-messages are not immediately sent. I regularly see arbitrarily high delays of printed debug messages. I think SQL Server waits for a network packet to be full, or some other kind of buffering.

If you just run an infinite loop that prints a small message every seconds you might get the first N messages after N seconds all at once. This might only be the case over TCP. Maybe shared memory is quicker, I don't know.

I have never seen result sets to be delayed, though. So try "printing" by performing a `SELECT 'msg'`.

The issue of delayed writes to the client is well known as it seems:

1. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124994/print-output-lags-in-stored-procedure-it-is-always-delay-during-execution-of-a-batch-or-a-stored-procedure
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13047982/122718
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

On the other hand, all side-effects in your code (writing to a table or other DML) take place immediately anyway. Only the client app receives the `PRINT` messages delayed. This delay should not affect your production application at all because all the useful side-effects happen immediately.

In short, either ignore the problem or use `RAISERROR('Message', 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT`. An exception will only be thrown if the severity is greater than 10.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it kind of reads like you think I'm asking about fixing the delay in the PRINT.  I'm not - although the behavior is similar.  I'm already doing a select.  (BTW, doing another select in the loop like `SELECT 0` is delayed along with the message I want - I can't seem to force it to flush.  Yet the queue is emptied of the held-up message!

Comment: With the element already dequeued but not sent to the client, this sounds like a case of network buffering. Try this: insert the element into a different table, and check the table contents from a different session (using READUNCOMMITTED). My suspicion is that the dequeued elements will show up there immediately. This would prove that all your SSB code is good. Only the delivery to the client would be broken. And you could fix the delivery by moving the loop into the client app. With SSMS you can test this using `GO 100` syntax to send 100 batches to the server.

Comment: I will try the write to a table idea, that's good. I don't want to move the loop to the application although I think that would work because the full results always show up when the command completes.

Comment: Can you tell more about why you need the PRINT messages to arrive on time? This appears not to be a problem to me because the processing is not delayed at all, only the message. If you require immediate prints I have added some stuff about it.

Comment: again, I'm *not at all* interested in `PRINT`s.  I am only interested in getting the message delivered immediately.  `PRINT` behavior was only mentioned for comparison.  I appreciate your edit for completeness on the RAISERROR with low severity, but note that nimdil had posted that answer first.  So if that's the best possible workaround I have to give it to nimdil.

Comment: I do not quite understand because the messages *are* being delivered instantly. Don't you agree? I also want to add that I discovered the issue of delayed prints first :) That was key.

Comment: No, the messages aren't being delivered instantly.  That was the original problem.  And I mentioned the similarity to `PRINT` in my original post.