# Flush print statements to client (SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Please see the code below:

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
AS
BEGIN
begin tran
begin try
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ID int
    DECLARE @Count int
    set @Count=0
    DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id
FROM Person3;
OPEN Employee_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN    
        WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:01'
        SET @Count = @Count+1
        Print @Count        
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @ID;
   END;
   commit tran
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;
end try
begin catch
ROLLBACK tran
end catch
END
```

The stored procedure runs and then the following output is flushed to the client all at once (because there are three records in: person3):

```
1
2
3
```

How do you flush the output to the client on each iteration of the cursor? I am looking for an answer that is compatible with SQL Server 2005.

I have tried usinbg the RAISEERROR statement as desribed here: [How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql), however all the statements still appear at the end.

Comment: You can use GO (batch seperator) to flush messages, but since you are in a transaction (giant batch) I don't think that will work.  Also, cursors and WAITFOR should be avoided in SQL if possible.

Comment: Have you tried the exact same query without the try/catch block?

Comment: With RAISERROR('foo', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT :: the output shows up in the Messages tab in SSMS during query execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I flush the PRINT buffer in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql)

Answer (score 2):

Use the combination of a RAISERROR severity of 0 to 10 and the WITH NOWAIT clause for a statement that sends output to the Messages windows immediately.

```
RAISERROR ('Now that''s what I call a message!', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Reference: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/