# Why statement running slow within a while operation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016 (localDB). I have the following DB script which takes 8 seconds, however, the `select` statement only take 0 seconds if I run separately. Actually that `select` statement always return 0 rows.

Do you know why it is slow in this case?

PS: I have another similar statement, which works fine, only this one takes super long.

```
while exists (select *
              from vidyoRoomCall vrc
              inner join reportEffectiveRoomUsage eu on vrc.vidyoRoomId = eu.vidyoRoomId
                                                     and vrc.leaveTime is not null
                                                     and datediff(second, vrc.joinTime, vrc.leaveTime) < 100000 -- @max_second
              where (vrc.joinTime between eu.[start] and eu.[end] 
                     and vrc.leaveTime > eu.[end])
                 or (vrc.leaveTime between eu.[start] and eu.[end] 
                     and vrc.joinTime < eu.[start])
             )
begin
    print 'ignore this since it is only run here' -- this never print
end
```

Comment: did you see any prints for those 8 seconds?

Comment: Looping always will be slow. As SQL developed base SET theory the sql server engine will work more efficient with Joins than procedural approach like looping. So Select taking lesser time where while is looping all those records

Comment: Are you trying to grab a row at a time by any chance?

Comment: IF you are asking why it is slower when you wrap it in `exists` this may be because you get different plans due to the [row goal](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx). What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: Please confirm that `PRINT` never returns anything, as it may be a case where [print results are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql)

Comment: Hi Yes the `PRINT` never runs.

Comment: The only problem is why the `select` statement runs slow within `while` loop, and the `select` statement return 0 records

Answer (score 0):

It keeps running until the inner code is true... So probably for a period of 8 seconds, the query returned some results. At the end of 8 seconds, last SELECT did not return any rows which ended the WHILE loop. This is the reason it took 8 seconds.
Probably, your code executed hundreds of inner query which returned some rows everytime. So there is no performance difference. Only WHILE loop ...

Comment: I've updated the question, actually the select statement return always `0` records. So, the while statement never enters.